# How to speed up iteration through array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have multiple csv files that have the name and the price of products. There may be or may not be products that are in both files. I have to find the highest and the lowest price across these files for each product.

I joined products from both files into one array:

```
Dir["./*.csv"].each do |file|
  CSV.foreach(file, headers:true) do |row|
    tmpRow = row.to_s.chomp + "," + file #saving name of the input file
    list.push(tmpRow.chomp.split(","))
  end
end
```

The array `list` looks like this:

```
[["5893105","2.38", "weightOrSomethingIrrelevant", "./FIAT_2.csv"]]
```

This is the main algorithm:

```
while list[0] do
  if list[0] != nil
    tmpPart = list[0][0]
    tmpParts = list.select{ |part, price| part == tmpPart}
    tmpParts.each do |tp|
      tmpPrices.push(tp[1])
    end
    list[0][2].to_f != 0.0 ? tmpWeight = list[0][2].to_s : tmpWeight = "Undefined"
    tmpMaxPrice = tmpParts.select{|part, price| part == tmpPart && price == tmpPrices.max}
    tmpMinPrice = tmpParts.select{|part, price| part == tmpPart && price == tmpPrices.min}
    result.push([tmpPart, tmpWeight, tmpPrices.max, tmpMaxPrice[0].last, tmpPrices.min, tmpMinPrice[0].last)
    tmpPart = ""
    list = list - tmpParts
    tmpParts = []
    tmpPrices = []
    tmpMaxPrice = []
    tmpMinPrice = []
    tmpWeight = ""
  end
end
```

The input files are huge (over 200 000 rows), so I am having problems with efficiency of my algorithm (as it processes one row in half a second).

I am wondering if there is any better way to write this app.

Comment: Do you have an example CSV you can share? It's hard to say what exactly can be done without seeing the file itself. Also, https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby has some benchmarks of methods and comparable methods that could help you trim off some time.

Comment: is this line right? `tmpRow = row.to_s.chomp + "," + file`.  `file` in this case would be the entire read file not the name.  Your while loop is O(n^2) but tough to help without knowing the data of the files.

Comment: Have you considered loading your CSVs into an SQLite database (or other database that you might have available)? CSV is a decent enough format for data interchange but it isn't a database and writing your own in-memory database and indexing system (which is what your arrays are) seems unnecessary when so many tools already exist.

Comment: Link to example csv file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t6u6zeBUM49kmb3k9MYkTO4qZdxRJuSu Only first two columns matter there. First column is ID, second is price. Also file variable in tmpRow = row.to_s.chomp + "," + file is actually a string "./FIAT_2.csv".

Answer (score 1):

I would split this into several parts:
1) I suggest you have a table which represents files (the file name, location, line number etc) and connected to that a product table (the row data from that file)
2) script / function to ingest files and store rows as DB records
3) script / function to analyse rows and find products by name, using the DB and pulling price info out using Min/max.

This could later be improved to deal with naming inconsistencies products vs product occurrences etc.